# Don't understand `destruct` tactic on hypothesis `~ (exists x : X, ~ P x)` in Coq

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I'm new to Coq and try to learn it through [Software foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/). In the chapter "Logic in Coq", there is an exercise `not_exists_dist` which I completed (by guessing) but not understand:

```
Theorem not_exists_dist :
  excluded_middle →
  ∀ (X:Type) (P : X → Prop),
    ¬ (∃ x, ¬ P x) → (∀ x, P x).
Proof.
  intros em X P H x.
  destruct (em (P x)) as [T | F].
  - apply T.
  - destruct H.              (* <-- This step *)
    exists x.
    apply F.
Qed.
```

Before the `destruct`, the context and goal looks like:

```
em: excluded_middle
X: Type
P: X -> Prop
H: ~ (exists x : X, ~ P x)
x: X
F: ~ P x
--------------------------------------
(1/1)
P x
```

And after it

```
em: excluded_middle
X: Type
P: X -> Prop
x: X
F: ~ P x
--------------------------------------
(1/1)
exists x0 : X, ~ P x0
```

While I understand `destruct` on `P /\ Q` and `P \/ Q` in hypothesis, I don't understand how it works on `P -> False` like here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try to give some intuition behind this by doing another proof first.
Consider:

```
Goal forall A B C : Prop, A -> C -> (A \/ B -> B \/ C -> A /\ B) -> A /\ B. 
Proof.
  intros. (*eval up to here*)
Admitted.
```

What you will see in `*goals*` is:

```
1 subgoal (ID 77)
  
  A, B, C : Prop
  H : A
  H0 : C
  H1 : A ∨ B → B ∨ C → A ∧ B
  ============================
  A ∧ B
```

Ok, so we need to show `A /\ B`. We can use `split` to break the and apart, thus we need to show `A` and `B`. `A` follows easily by assumption, `B` is something we do not have. So, our proof script now might look like:

```
Goal forall A B C : Prop, A -> C -> (A \/ B -> B \/ C -> A /\ B) -> A /\ B. 
Proof.
  intros. split; try assumption. (*eval up to here*)
Admitted.
```

With goals:

```
1 subgoal (ID 80)
  
  A, B, C : Prop
  H : A
  H0 : C
  H1 : A ∨ B → B ∨ C → A ∧ B
  ============================
  B
```

The only way we can get to the `B` is by somehow using H1. Let's see what `destruct H1` does to our goals:

```
3 subgoals (ID 86)
  
  A, B, C : Prop
  H : A
  H0 : C
  ============================
  A ∨ B

subgoal 2 (ID 87) is:
 B ∨ C
subgoal 3 (ID 93) is:
 B
```

We get additional subgoals! In order to destruct H1 we need to provide it proofs for `A \/ B` and `B \/ C`, we cannot destruct `A /\ B` otherwise!

For the sake of completeness: (without the `split;try assumption` shorthand)

```
Goal forall A B C : Prop, A -> C -> (A \/ B -> B \/ C -> A /\ B) -> A /\ B. 
Proof.
  intros. split.
  - assumption.
  - destruct H1.
    + left. assumption.
    + right. assumption.
    + assumption.
Qed.
```

Another way to view it is this: H1 is a function that takes `A \/ B` and `B \/ C` as input. `destruct` works on its output. In order to destruct the result of such a function, you need to give it an appropriate input.
Then, `destruct` performs a case analysis without introducing additional goals.
We can do that in the proof script as well before `destruct`ing:

```
Goal forall A B C : Prop, A -> C -> (A \/ B -> B \/ C -> A /\ B) -> A /\ B. 
Proof.
  intros. split.
  - assumption.
  - specialize (H1 (or_introl H) (or_intror H0)).
    destruct H1.
    assumption.
Qed.
```

From a proof term perspective, `destruct` of `A /\ B` is the same as `match A /\ B with conj H1 H2 => (*construct a term that has your goal as its type*) end`.
We can replace the `destruct` in our proof script with a corresponding `refine` that does exactly that:

```
Goal forall A B C : Prop, A -> C -> (A \/ B -> B \/ C -> A /\ B) -> A /\ B. 
Proof.
  intros. unfold not in H0. split.
  - assumption.
  - specialize (H1 (or_introl H) (or_intror H0)).
    refine (match H1 with conj Ha Hb => _ end).
    exact Hb.
Qed.
```

---

Back to your proof. Your goals before `destruct`

```
em: excluded_middle
X: Type
P: X -> Prop
H: ~ (exists x : X, ~ P x)
x: X
F: ~ P x
--------------------------------------
(1/1)
P x
```

After applying the `unfold not in H` tactic you see:

```
em: excluded_middle
X: Type
P: X -> Prop
H: (exists x : X, P x -> ⊥) -> ⊥
x: X
F: ~ P x
--------------------------------------
(1/1)
P x
```

Now recall the definition of ⊥: It's a proposition that cannot be constructed, i.e. *it has no constructors*.
If you somehow have ⊥ as an assumption and you destruct, you essentially look at the type of `match ⊥ with end`, which can be anything.

In fact, we can prove *any* goal with it:

```
Goal (forall (A : Prop), A) <-> False.  (* <- note that this is different from *)
Proof.                                  (*    forall (A : Prop), A <-> False   *)
  split; intros.
  - specialize (H False). assumption.
  - refine (match H with end).
Qed.
```

Its proofterm is:

```
(λ (A B C : Prop) (H : A) (H0 : C) (H1 : A ∨ B → B ∨ C → A ∧ B),
   conj H (let H2 : A ∧ B := H1 (or_introl H) (or_intror H0) in match H2 with
                                                                | conj _ Hb => Hb
                                                                end))
```

Anyhow, `destruct` on your assumption `H` will give you a proof for your goal if you are able to show `exists x : X, ~ P x -> ⊥`.

Instead of `destruct`, you could also do `exfalso. apply H.` to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your detail explanation and i've learned some new things from your answer :-). If understand correctly, `destruct` on `P -> Q` is telling coq that i want to `destruct` on `Q`, and coq add `P` as subgoal as a precondtion.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, `destruct t` applies when `t` is an inhabitant of an inductive type `I`, giving you one goal for each possible constructor for `I` that could have been used to produce `t`. Here as you remarked `H` has type `P -> False`, which is not an inductive type, but `False` is. So what happens is this: `destruct` gives you a first goal corresponding to the `P` hypothesis of `H`. Applying `H` to that goal leads to a term of type `False`, which is an inductive type, on which `destruct` works as it should, giving you zero goals since `False` has no constructors. Many tactics for inductive types work like this on hypothesis of the form `P1 -> … -> Pn -> I` where `I` is an inductive type: they give you side-goals for `P1` … `Pn`, and then work on `I`.

Comment: Thanks, now i know that destruct on `P -> Q` is actually destruct on `Q`, with `P` added as a subgoal. And if `Q` is `False` like here, the original goal disappear since exfalso thus only the subgoal `P` left to be proved.